# How to stop last instance of a dynamic form element from being deleted?

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, fadeout, dynamic-forms

its probably easier if you can have a look at the code in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/qe2zt/

Bascially, all I want to do is stop the last set of dropdowns from being able to be deleted and as a bonus - figure out how to fade out the deletes aswell - I couldn't get that to work for some reason.

Thanks for any help, it's much appreciated.

Regards,

Martin

Comment: I think you should keep some counters to manage the number of rows. check if the number is the last row. If so hide the delete button using it's id only on the particular row

Comment: To clarify, you want the last option of each select to remain when you delete the options, right? What is it you want to fade out? The text of the selected option if that option is deleted?

Comment: yeah so you can add and delete rows of dropdowns as you wish but if there is only one left then there shouldn't be an option to delete it until a new row is added.

And what I want to fade out is the row of dropdowns when you delete - just the same as when you add a new row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added code to fade out the deleted drop downs.

http://jsfiddle.net/6xPye/1/

Also, the following code:

```
    if ($(this).is(".dropdown")) {
        $(".dropdownclone:first").toggleClass("dropdown dropdownclone");
    }
    $(this).remove();
```

Assures that if the user deletes the top row there is still a .dropdown for the `addNew()` function to clone.

Comment: thank you, that's absolutely perfect. The only thing I would like now is to hide the delete button when the page loads until a new row is added. Do you have any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: You could just add "display: none;" to a style attribute on the image in the html as I've done here: http://jsfiddle.net/6xPye/2/

Answer (score 1):

i modified it:

http://jsfiddle.net/scheffield/esEmh/

Essentially I added a function `remove`

```
function remove(element) {
    var amountEntries = $('.dropdown').size() + $('.dropdownclone').size();
    if (amountEntries  <= 1) {
        return;
    }
    if (amountEntries === 2) {
        $('.deleteButton').hide();
    }
    element.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(element.parentNode);
}
```

It's not exactly perfect but it works...

Comment: thanks you very much, it works when you get back to the last one, but if you add more,  the remove button doesn't reappear :/

Comment: @marincarlin87: I know, but as i wrote it's not a perfect soloution, it's a hint how to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to get the delete button to show again but my code doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/esEmh/9/ . I think it looks ok, can't see what's stopping it?

Comment: thanks - i don't want to be a pest but after trying to add to your update I couldn't fix the bug - when you are one the last one and try to add a new one it only adds a remove button instead of a new row. 

I thought my code would have worked (again) but it didn't :S